# Problem resolving URL for a Script Tag in an ASP.NET app in the Intranet

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have this piece of code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), this.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/min.js"));
```

When we push to our QA server - http://qa.example.com - it works just fine, but when we push to an address in the intranet - http://intranet/app - it won't find the script.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would advise you don't use NewGuid() as the key, every time you place that RegisterClientScriptInclude(...) it will generate a link.  The type,key, and url are combined by the ClientScriptManager and checked so the link only appears once in the output....

Comment: I agree, but we use ajax so we do not postback at all, so the registration of the script should only happen once. But thanks for the observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Intranet's root is http://intranet not http://intranet/app - your RegisterClientScriptInclude in is looking in http://intranet/scripts/min.js not http://intranet/app/scripts.

Comment: Not really... when I look at the generated code, it looks like: <script src="/app/Scripts/min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>, so the reference is correct.

Comment: Couple of ways to go then, 1, fire up Fiddler and examine why the request for /app/scripts/min.js fails, probably access denied or not found. 2. Manually construct the url in the address bar http://intranet/app/scripts/min.js -

Comment: after typing the above - I will to place a small bet on it being permissions on the scripts folder, provided you actually copied the script over to the server!

Comment: it was actually a permissions problem.. but it should give me an exception, not simply load the page without the scripts! thanks anyways!

Comment: Browsers get 404 or 50x errors when they can't access a resource that the server cannot find or allow them to have.
Servers do not push to the client, clients pull from the server. That's why asp.net did not throw an exception.